# DropDownList doesn't show enough rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

In ASP.NET, a `ListBox` has a Rows attribute I can set to say how many rows to show.  A `DropDownList`, though, doesn't.  Is there any way I can set the maximum number of rows a `DropDownList` should display?  Code?  Markup?  CSS?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that level of control, you are left to re-implement drop down lists in javascript.  Kinda sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdownlist is rendered in a browser as html select... html
select does not support the requirements you are asking...

You will need to write a custom control to set the limit on max number of rows.

you got to write a custom control for that or use client side add-ins...

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427801/dropdownlist-number-of-display-element) also answers your question.